# C++ cin only accept numeric values

Tags: c++, validation

I've written this piece of code that allows the user to choose input either the value 1 or 2. This is working perfectly fine aside from one minor issue:

If the user inputs something like "1asdaosd" the input is recognized only as 1.

I've tried using the isdigit function but I still didn't manage to make this work.

```
bool validInput;
    do
    {
        cout << "Choose the game type: ";
        cin >> gametype;
        validInput = true;
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            validInput = false;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
        }
        if (gametype<1 || gametype>2) {
            validInput = false;
        }
    } while (!validInput);
```

The expected behaviour should be:

Anything other than "1" or "2" shouldn't be considered a validInput and therefore repeating the cycle. What happens is that "1asdasd" or "2aods" is considered a validInput but I want it to fail.

Comment: What is the type of `gametype`?

Comment: But isn't that what you want: for the user to only input 1 or 2?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want "1asdkoas" to be considered a valid input.

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe the behavior that you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a method based on stuff I read in one of the early chapters of Stroustrup's *Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++* and an [answer](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/42594/) provided by Duoas at cplusplus.com. It defines a function, `get_int_between()`, that allows you to do something like this:

```
int my_variable;
get_int_between(my_variable, min, max, prompt, error_msg);
```

Which would prompt, validate, and store into my_variable.

Just for fun, I've also included a function, `get_int(my_variable, prompt, error_msg)`, that does the same thing but allows an integer of any value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> // stringstream

void get_int(int& d, std::string prompt, std::string fail);

void get_int_between(int& d, int min, int max, std::string prompt, std::string fail);

int main()
{
    int my_number = 1; // initialize my_number

    get_int(my_number, "Please enter an integer: ", "Sorry, that's not an integer.\n"); 
    //Do something, e.g. 
    std::cout << "You entered: " << my_number << "\n";

    get_int_between(my_number, 1, 2, "Choose the game type (1 or 2): ", "Sorry, that's not an integer.\n");
    //Do something, e.g.:
    std::cout << "Let's play Game " << my_number << "!\n";

    return 0;
}

void get_int(int& d, std::string prompt, std::string fail)
{
    while(1) {

        std::cout << prompt;
        std::string str;
        std::cin >> str;

        std::istringstream ss(str);
        int val1;
        ss >> val1;

        if(!ss.eof()) {
            std::cout << fail;
            continue;
        } else {
            d = val1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void get_int_between(int& d, int min, int max, std::string prompt, std::string fail)
{
    while(1) {
        get_int(d, prompt, fail);
        if(d > max || d < min) {
            std::cout << "Sorry, your choice is out of range.\n";
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use strings use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/).

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout
int main () 
{
char name[256], title[256];

std::cout << "Please, enter your name: ";
std::cin.getline (name,256);

std::cout << "Please, enter your favourite movie: ";
std::cin.getline (title,256);

std::cout << name << "'s favourite movie is " << title;

return 0;
}
```

if you make gametype as an *int* it will only accept 1 or 2 (of course you have to prevent other numbers to be accepted).

Answer (score 0):

It's because `gametype` is an integer, so it's trying to read as much as would be valid for an integer. `1asdaosd` is not a valid integer so it stops at the `1`. If you want to read that thing in completely you'll have to make `gametype` a string for example, but then you won't be able to compare it to integers as you already do.

You can read it as a string if you want, and if you want to handle the case of strings and ints both, then you can use something like [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to attempt to convert the string to an integer. Then catch the `std::invalid_argument` exception so you can know if the string *can* be converted to an integer. If it can't, then you know to keep it as a string.

Comment: I've tried doing this, but "1asdasod" doesn't throw any exceptions:
`code`
  try {
   gametype = stoi(tempinput);
  } catch (std::invalid_argument) {
   validInput=false;
  }
`code`

tempinput being a string and gametype being an int

Comment: @RuiGomes Yeah I guess you can't do it this way. If you print out `gametype` it should be `1` given the input you put in the question. Another option is to iterate through the string with [`isdigit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) and if every element in the string passes then you can assume it's an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It reads an int as far the input can be construed as such. Then stops. If you read into a string variable it will get it all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read data into a string variable.
2. Check that data is a valid integer.
3. Convert string to integer.

Tedious but it's the only way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want one input value on each line. You need to read this as string and then check if you got more than you asked for. If you need it as an integer you can convert the read string later.

I'm also assuming you only need to read single digit integers. More digits need the string to integer conversion in the loop and some more checks.

```
string gametype;
do
{
    cout << "Choose the game type: ";
    // read one word as string, no conversion, so will not fail (may hit eof though)
    cin >> gametype;
    // ignore rest of line (assuming you want next valid input on next line)
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
}
while ( gametype.size() != 1 || gametype.at(0) < '1' || gametype.at(0) > '2') );

// char to int conversion (single digit only)
int gametypeint = gametype.at(0) - '0';

// other way to convert string to int
istringstream iss(gametype);
iss >> gametypeint;

// yet another way (C++11)
gametypeint = stio(gametype);
```